# How to display the same bootstrap 4 card structure in mobile as in desktop?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display the bootstrap card in a mobile view as same as it look in the desktop version. I try to find it on google but no helping result found. no snippet!
As you can see in the below image the looks of the bootstrap v4 card.

**Desktop view**

[image: here]

**Current mobile view**

[image: mobile]

**What I want:**

I am figuring out the way to view the card into mobile view as same as it looks in the desktop view.

**Example with photoshop:**

[image: shop]

```css
/**Product item styling **/
.ratings i {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red
}

.strike-text {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through
}

.product-image {
    width: 100%
}

.dot {
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block
}

.spec-1 {
    color: #938787;
    font-size: 15px
}

h5 {
    font-weight: 400
}

.para {
    font-size: 16px
}

.txt-wrp-on-btn
{
    overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">  
    <div class="row p-2 bg-white border rounded mt-2 mb-2" style="min-height: 130px;">
      <div class="col-md-4 mt-1">
             <img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/VL3w7MC/WJXt0n8-Oimy34fxuz-Ihw.jpg">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-5 mt-1">
         <span class="text-primary " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6 Pc Meal">
                    <strong>6 Pc Meal</strong>
         </span>

                  <!-- PRICE SECTION -->

                  <!-- IF SERVINGS IS MENU -->
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                        <h4 class="mr-1 text-success h6">$20.68</h4>
                        <small class="strike-text mb-2">$22.76</small>
                      </div>
                 <!-- IF SERVINGS IS PLATE -->
                  <p class="text-justify text-truncate para mb-0">
                     3 Thighs and 2 Drums along with Large box of Taters                         </p>

            </div>
               <div class="align-items-center align-content-center col-md-3 border-left mt-1">


                 <!-- DETAIL ICON -->
                 <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-1">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showModalWithHeader('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/menu/20', '6 Pc Meal')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm txt-wrp-on-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-info-circle" ></i> 
                  </a>

                  <!-- FAVOURITE ICON -->
                                    <a href="#" class="far fa-heart btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2 txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="confirm_modal('https://domain/favourite/update/20')"></a>

                  <!-- ADD TO CART -->
                      <div class="closed-now">

                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=" btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mt-2 btn-block txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="showCartModal('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/cart/20', 'Add to cart')"> <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span></a>

                  

                 </div>
                 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have changed bootstrap column classes. If you want the same view similar to the desktop you can directly add bootstrap column classes `col-*`.

For example:
`col-md-4` to `col-4`.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/y15m3nhj/1/

```css
/**Product item styling **/
.ratings i {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red
}

.strike-text {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through
}

.product-image {
    width: 100%
}

.dot {
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block
}

.spec-1 {
    color: #938787;
    font-size: 15px
}

h5 {
    font-weight: 400
}

.para {
    font-size: 16px
}

.txt-wrp-on-btn
{
    overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row p-2 bg-white border rounded mt-2 mb-2" style="min-height: 130px;">
    <div class="col-4 mt-1">
      <img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/VL3w7MC/WJXt0n8-Oimy34fxuz-Ihw.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 mt-1">
      <span class="text-primary " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6 Pc Meal">
        <strong>6 Pc Meal</strong>
      </span>

      <!-- PRICE SECTION -->

      <!-- IF SERVINGS IS MENU -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-row align-items-center">
        <h4 class="mr-1 text-success h6">$20.68</h4>
        <small class="strike-text mb-2">$22.76</small>
      </div>
      <!-- IF SERVINGS IS PLATE -->
      <p class="text-justify text-truncate para mb-0">
        3 Thighs and 2 Drums along with Large box of Taters </p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-3 align-items-center align-content-center border-left mt-1">


      <!-- DETAIL ICON -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showModalWithHeader('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/menu/20', '6 Pc Meal')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm txt-wrp-on-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        </a>

        <!-- FAVOURITE ICON -->
        <a href="#" class="far fa-heart btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2 txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="confirm_modal('https://domain/favourite/update/20')"></a>

        <!-- ADD TO CART -->
        <div class="closed-now">

          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=" btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mt-2 btn-block txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="showCartModal('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/cart/20', 'Add to cart')"> <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span></a>



        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with Cards Elements from bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of some [`col-sm-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) classes for mobile specific design. I have added the comments wherever the code was edited with a prefix `EDIT:`

```css
/**Product item styling **/

.ratings i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red
}

.strike-text {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%
}

.dot {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block
}

.spec-1 {
  color: #938787;
  font-size: 15px
}

h5 {
  font-weight: 400
}

.para {
  font-size: 16px
}

.txt-wrp-on-btn {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> <!-- EDIT: 12 columns on smaller screen -->
  <div class="row p-2 bg-white border rounded mt-2 mb-2" style="min-height: 130px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-1 col-sm-4"> <!-- EDIT: Subdivide 12 columns into 4 for the image -->
      <img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded product-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/VL3w7MC/WJXt0n8-Oimy34fxuz-Ihw.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 mt-1 col-sm-6"> <!-- EDIT: Create 6 columns for the center part -->
      <span class="text-primary " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6 Pc Meal">
                    <strong>6 Pc Meal</strong>
         </span>

      <!-- PRICE SECTION -->

      <!-- IF SERVINGS IS MENU -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <h4 class="mr-1 text-success h6">$20.68</h4>
        <small class="strike-text mb-2">$22.76</small>
      </div>
      <!-- IF SERVINGS IS PLATE -->
      <p class="text-justify text-truncate para mb-0">
        3 Thighs and 2 Drums along with Large box of Taters </p>

    </div>
    <div class="align-items-center align-content-center col-md-3 border-left mt-1 col-sm-2"> <!-- EDIT: Remaining two columns for the last part -->


      <!-- DETAIL ICON -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showModalWithHeader('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/menu/20', '6 Pc Meal')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm txt-wrp-on-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        </a>

        <!-- FAVOURITE ICON -->
        <a href="#" class="far fa-heart btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2 txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="confirm_modal('https://domain/favourite/update/20')"></a>

        <!-- ADD TO CART -->
        <div class="closed-now">

          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=" btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mt-2 btn-block txt-wrp-on-btn" onclick="showCartModal('https://domain/modal/showup/restaurant/cart/20', 'Add to cart')"> <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span></a>



        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I really appreciate it. but its not my answer.